# Is it possible to reference a further parent than just the one above?

Tags: sass

I have the following sample code:

```
.level1 {
   // css

  .level2 {
  // css

     . level3 {
     // css
     color: red;
  }
}
```

And then

```
.level1.blue .level .level3 {
  color: blue
}
```

I would like to put the second rule somehow on the first bit of code, so that I don't repeat the structure again and I have both color possibilities above, is this possible in anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't planning on answering my own question, but it seems that I found out exactly what I was looking for only it has recently being added to sass and will be available on sass 3.4. I believe there's a prerelease to tried but I havent tried it yet.

Basically what I was looking has been answered to me on github:

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/286#issuecomment-49112243

So on 3.4 you can do:

```
.level1 {
  .level2 {
    .level3 {
       @at-root #{selector-append(".blue", &)} {
        color: blue;
      }
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

which is exactly what I was looking for.

There's a bunch of addition related to the parent selector (&), you can learn more from it at https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1117

Bear in mind though, that at the time of writing this answer, all of this is rather new.

Also see: https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md
And: http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-sass-3-4/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
@mixin level3color($color) {
  .level2 {
    .level3 {
      color: $color;
    }
  }
}

.level1 {
  @include level3color(#FF0000);

  &.blue {
    @include level3color(#0000FF);
  }
}
```

produces this:

```
.level1 .level2 .level3 {
  color: red;
}
.level1.blue .level2 .level3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Gotta love mixins!

EDIT:

This is still pretty clean (or at least clean considering what you're trying to do) because you can still have your structure there.

```
.level1 {
    // css

    .level2 {
        // css

        .level3 {
            // css
            color: red;
        }
    }

    &.blue   { @include level3color(blue); }
    &.yellow { @include level3color(yellow); }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but I kind of lose the cleaness of having altogeher. If I have css rules for both .level1, level2 and level3, but only a rule of level3 changes because of an extra class on level1, using this mixin will be very close to just having an extra rule below.

Comment: Well, unfortunately there's no way to go up multiple parents by doing, say, `&.blue & &`. The best I can figure, the solution I offered is the only way to do it.

Comment: And this still feels pretty clean if you ask me. You avoid repeating yourself and all you're doing is setting up the level 1 class and having it set up the scaffolding so it will apply to the level 3.

Comment: But consider the fact that you have more complex CSS structure with rules all over, you will still have tose lines below, and there might be more that just the color that I'd like to change, although you could do that with @content on the mixin. Still, I feel like this is almost the same as just having: .level1.blue .level2. level3 { ... } right below, it does add up for what I was looking for, which was to have the styles as close to each other as possible. After searching more and asking on github, I kind of found what I was looking for: bit.ly/1rgzXEd

Comment: Looks like that feature came out about 5 days ago. Very cool. Nice find! Add an answer on here for your question and check it so that people can learn about this.

Comment: Ok, just did it, thanks a lot though for taking the time to answer and discuss it!

Answer (score -2):

A simple example:

```
 .child{
    background-color:red;
    .parent:hover &{
      background-color:blue;
    }
  }
```

goes into

```
.child {
  background-color: red;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/e994e056d3cc3b342e2c

Comment: Not related to the question at all.  If the problem was as simple as this, it would have been closed as a duplicate.