# Compile error when converting less to sass

Tags: css, web, sass, less

Im very new to sass and less (and css in general) and need help converting some less to sass. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130489/less-to-sass-ampersand-workaround) question but still not sure how to do it. This snippet from less to sass is failing to compile in sass; can you advise what the correct format should be. This is the error:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    app\styles\mixins.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after ".dropdown-toggle": expected "{", was "&"

       "&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
        on line 12 of app/styles/mixins.scss
>>      .open .dropdown-toggle& {
```

**LESS**

```
.button-variant(@color; @background; @border) {
    color: @color;
    background-color: @background;
    border-color: @border;

    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active,
    .open .dropdown-toggle& {
        color: @color;
        background-color: darken(@background, 10%);
        border-color: darken(@border, 12%);
    }
    &:active,
    &.active,
    .open .dropdown-toggle& {
        background-image: none;
    }
    &.disabled,
    &[disabled],
    fieldset[disabled] & {
        &,
        &:hover,
        &:focus,
        &:active,
        &.active {
            background-color: @background;
            border-color: @border;
        }
    }
}
```

**SASS**

```
@mixin button-variant($color, $background, $border) {
    color: $color;
    background-color: $background;
    border-color: $border;

    &:hover,
    &:focus,
    &:active,
    &.active,
    .open .dropdown-toggle& {
        color: $color;
        background-color: darken($background, 10%);
        border-color: darken($border, 12%);
    }
    &:active,
    &.active,
    .open .dropdown-toggle& {
        background-image: none;
    }
    &.disabled,
    &[disabled],
    fieldset[disabled] & {
        &,
        &:hover,
        &:focus,
        &:active,
        &.active {
            background-color: $background;
            border-color: $border;
        }
    }

    .badge {
        color: $background;
        background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sass seems to have a problem when appending the parent selector (`&`) at the end without space (as another selector of same element). It works when appended at the end with space (that is, as selector for a child element).

**Solution 1:** Use the [`@at-root` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) to append the parent selector. Note that this seems to work only when the `@at-root` is used for the first selector in the group.

```css
@at-root .open .dropdown-toggle#{&},
&:hover,
&:focus,
&:active,
&.active {
    color: $color;
    background-color: darken($background, 10%);
    border-color: darken($border, 12%);
}
@at-root .open .dropdown-toggle#{&},
&:active,
&.active {
    background-image: none;
}
```

**Solution 2:** Add the `&` in between but before the last class selector. Order of class selectors doesn't matter in CSS and so the change shouldn't be a problem unless the parent selector is actually a chain of multiple elements' selectors. If that is/can be the case then refer to the first option.

```css
&:hover,
&:focus,
&:active,
&.active,
.open &.dropdown-toggle {
    color: $color;
    background-color: darken($background, 10%);
    border-color: darken($border, 12%);
}

&:active,
&.active,
.open &.dropdown-toggle {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: I wish there was something like @at-root to go up one level

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/less2sass. Install this and compress this

Comment: Short answers such as this one are generally better suited as comments.  You can support your response with a short code example.