# How to add a class to a nested child's parent using SASS?

Tags: css, sass, ampersand

This is a basic example but I would like to add a class to a parent in a nested child.

Desired CSS:

```
.addon .checkbox { background: blue; }
.addon.active .checkbox { background: red; }
```

Using SASS

```
 .addon {
       .checkbox { 
         background: blue; 
         .active & { background: red }
         .addon.active & { background: red }
       }
 }
```

This gives me the following:

```
.addon .checkbox {
  background: blue;
}
.active .addon .checkbox {
  background: red;
}
.addon.active .addon .checkbox {
  background: red;
}
```

As you can see I am not able to get the desired result using the & symbol. 
Can I do what I want using nesting or would I have to write it out using normal css ways.

Answered:

```
.addon {
    .checkbox { 
       background: blue; 
       @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '.addon', '.addon.active')} {
          background: red;
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764498/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-further-parent-than-just-the-one-above

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
.addon {
  .checkbox {...}

  &.active {
    .checkbox {...}
  }
}
```

Sadly, there's no shorter form for writing selectors like these.